# Считается ли память, находящаяся до ячейки памяти, на которую есть указатель, свободной?

Tags: c, массивы, память

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    numbers[0] = 2; numbers[1] = 3; numbers[2] = 4;
    numbers = numbers + 1;
    /* Далее ещё какой-то код */
    return 0;
}
```

Выделяется память под 3 значения типа `int`, затем указатель на эту область памяти смещается вправо.

Считается ли память, оставленная слева от указателя, свободной или это так и останется мусором? Безопасно ли к ней в дальнейшем обращаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
numbers = numbers + 1;
```

память `numbers[-1]` - это обыкновенная память, содержащая значение `2`, которое вы сами туда поместили. Можете обращаться к ней сколько угодно.

"Свободной" она, разумеется, не является. С чего бы это вдруг? Освободить память, выделенную `malloc`, можно только явным вызовом `free` или `realloc`.

И никаким "мусором" эта память не является тоже. С чего бы это вдруг? Как вы туда записали значение `2`, так это значение `2` там и хранится.

То, что происходит с памятью, никак не связано с тем, что происходит с указывающими на эту память указателями.

Comment: Я использую массив `*args[]` с системными аргументами. Я хотел избавиться от лишнего первого аргумента (Путь к исполняемому файлу). Тогда такой вопрос: если я выделяю память с помощью `malloc`, присваиваю указатель на эту память в какую-либо переменную, а потом этой переменной присваиваю значение `NULL`. Тогда эта память всё равно будет являться занятой, и её нельзя будет использовать?

Comment: @Don2Quixote: Да, если других указателей на эту память у вас не осталось. Освобождена она не будет, но доступ к этой памяти для вас будет потерян навсегда. Это классический пример *утечки памяти*.